# Switch to case insensitive in POSIX compliant shell script?

Tags: sh, case-insensitive

I'm translating a Windows-batch script to a Linux-shell script. This script is responsible for copying hundreds of different files from many unique locations to many unique locations. I've the problem that it's unknown for me, how those file names and directory names are written. Some files/directories use capital letters, some use small letters, it completely depends on the end users. But it's totally not important for me to know if those names are written in capital or small letters, I just want to be able to copy the files like on a Windows machine.

Example:

```
cp $SOURCE/XYZ/user1/*123456*.pdf --target-directory="$DEST/123456/abc/"
cp $SOURCE/XyZ/user2/*234567*.pdf --target-directory="$DEST/234567/aBc/"
```

Comment: POSIX specifies no such feature. If you're serious about looking for a POSIX shell feature as opposed to, say, an rsync feature or a way to cleverly leverage the `find` command, the answer is "no".

Comment: (Mind, on an operating system with a case insensitive file system this will all be taken care of under the hood without the shell needing to know anything about it).

Comment: Linux may be able to mount a case insensitive file system, but that would break POSIX compliance.

Comment: @paladin I don't think POSIX has anything to say about file-system behavior.

Comment: It does, but the POSIX _sh_ standard doesn't say anything about filesystem behavior; entirely distinct sections. (And POSIX has a lot less to say about filesystem behavior than people often assume; the set of characters guaranteed to be valid in filenames is surprisingly small).

Answer (score 0):

As I'm dependent on my script to be POSIX compliant, I've created a small function which hopefully "translates" any given path to the actual path, ignoring case-sensitive.

`findpath_example.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE=/tmp

touch $SOURCE/ABC.TMP && echo "THIS IS A TEST" > $SOURCE/ABC.TMP

findpath()
{
  KNOWNPATH=$1
  PATTERNPATH=$2
  find $KNOWNPATH > /tmp/findpath$$.tmp
  FOUNDPATH=$(grep --ignore-case "$KNOWNPATH/$PATTERNPATH" /tmp/findpath$$.tmp | head --lines=1)
  echo $FOUNDPATH
  rm /tmp/findpath$$.tmp
}

cat $SOURCE/abc.tmp             # this will fail
cat $(findpath $SOURCE abc.tmp) # this will work

rm $SOURCE/ABC.TMP
```

This is a bit slow but it works.

Comment: Please run this through http://shellcheck.net/ (there are a _lot_ of quoting bugs -- more of them will be shown in shellcheck's output, by the way, if you change `SOURCE=/tmp` to `SOURCE=$1`), and also think about using lower-case variable names, as recommended by the POSIX spec -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, indicating that the shell and other POSIX-compliant tools use all-caps names for variables that modify or reflect their operation, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use.

Comment: BTW, you could probably avoid the need for a temporary file given a `while read` loop. And while it's difficult to support these correctly while using only POSIX-defined functionality, note that newline literals are often permitted in filenames, so someone wanting to make your script behave in surprising ways could potentially create a name that in bash might be described as `"$SOURCE"/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/hi-there.pdf` -- meaning that using non-POSIX extensions that make permit NUL-delimited streams instead of newline-delimited ones is often a correctness/robustness/security improvement.

Comment: Depending on how large the tree you need to search is, btw, the performance improvement from writing sed code (or such) to translate to `[Xx][Yy][Zz]/[Uu][Ss][Ee][Rr]1` (etc) and then expanding that unquoted after clearing IFS might be worth the hassle, since a shell expanding that doesn't need to recurse down directories that couldn't possibly be a match, whereas find obviously does.

Comment: Also, note that `--ignore-case` is a GNU extension. For POSIX compliance you just want `grep -i`; https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html sets out what a POSIX-compliant `grep` is guaranteed to support.